# Drop database works with multiple attempts after manually deleting .bak files

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2012

This is an odd problem. We have a program that installs 2 databases using C# in Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

When the program gets uninstalled, the databases aren't dropped. When the user re-installs the program, it checks if the databases are still inside the server and then drops them, and then recreates the dropped databases.

The database `.bak` files gets created in the `C:/Program Files` or equivalent folder. Now the problem is, if you manually delete the `.bak` files after the uninstall and try to reinstall the program it fails (obviously).

But if you try to install the program thrice it eventually manages to create the 2 databases.

Here's the C# code

```
String path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

Server server = InitializeServer(log);
server.ConnectionContext.Connect();

Database db = server.Databases["ADB"];  

if (db != null) 
{
    try
    {
        db.Drop();//-------------------------First try fails here
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(ex.Message);
    }
}

try  //----------------- second try database ADB gets created
{
    Restore restore = new Restore();

    // Set type of backup to be performed to database
    restore.Database = "ADB";
    restore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
    restore.ReplaceDatabase = true;

    // Create the Restore database ldf & mdf file name
    String dataFileLocation = path + "ADB" + ".mdf";
    String logFileLocation = path + "ADB" + "_Log.ldf";
    RelocateFile rf = new RelocateFile("ADB", dataFileLocation);

    // Set up the backup device to use filesystem. 
    restore.Devices.AddDevice(path + "\\ADB.bak", DeviceType.File);

    System.Data.DataTable logicalRestoreFiles = restore.ReadFileList(server);
    restore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(logicalRestoreFiles.Rows[0][0].ToString(), dataFileLocation));
    restore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(logicalRestoreFiles.Rows[1][0].ToString(), logFileLocation));
    restore.NoRecovery = false;

    restore.SqlRestore(server);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new ApplicationException(ex.Message);
}

// Installing 2nd database----------------------------------------------
server.ConnectionContext.Connect();

Database db1 = server.Databases["BDB"]; 

if (db1 != null)
{
    try
    {
        db1.Drop();//-------------------------Second try fails here
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(ex.Message);
    }
}

try //----------------- Third try database BDB gets created
{
    Restore restore2 = new Restore();
    restore2.Database = "BDB";
    restore2.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
    restore2.ReplaceDatabase = true;

    String dataFileLocation = path + "BDB" + ".mdf";
    String logFileLocation = path + "BDB" + "_Log.ldf";

    RelocateFile rf = new RelocateFile("BDB", dataFileLocation);

    restore2.Devices.AddDevice(path + "\\BDB.bak", DeviceType.File);

    System.Data.DataTable logicalRestoreFiles = restore2.ReadFileList(server);
    restore2.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(logicalRestoreFiles.Rows[0][0].ToString(), dataFileLocation));
    restore2.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(logicalRestoreFiles.Rows[1][0].ToString(), logFileLocation));
    restore2.NoRecovery = false;

    restore2.SqlRestore(server);
}
```

My questions are, is there a way to detach the server database after `.bak` files have been manually deleted? And why does the database gets created with the 2nd attempt?

Edit:
Here is the error message I receive when dropping a DB

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: Drop failed for Database 'ADB'.  ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot drop the database 'ADB', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection sqlCommands, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection queries)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection queries, Boolean includeDbContext)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.DropImplWorker(Urn& urn)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.DropImpl()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.DropImpl()
   at SetupScripts.SetupDataBase.Execute(FrmLog log)
```

Comment: I think this is not good idea, then why user should delete `bak` file ? why you don't define schedule to get backup per day or month or... if your DB is very sensitive

Comment: Seeing as your drop fails, what error message does it show? My guess would be something about it cannot drop due to open/active connections?

Comment: I've added the error message. In the InitializeServer(log) method, I do stop and start MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS. Could the drop succeed because of multiple stops and starts?